# Print out large JSON_DECODE object in meaningful manner?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm working on a website that I make heavy use of json objects. I have a very, very large json object that contains, from what it looks like, dozens of arrays of arrays of arrays of etc...

I've been doing my normal method of just doing:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
if( $obj == NULL )
    echo "JSON NULL!<br>";
else{                                                                            

    echo "here!!<br>";
    foreach( $obj as $key=>$val ){
        foreach( $val as $k=>$v){

            echo "$k <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is not very meaningful and I find it hard to tell what is the parent of what in terms of being able to access the individual items in a `$obj["one"]["two"]["three]"` manner.

I've looked around quite a bit and there are many examples of using json_decode in foreach arrays, but all the examples I've found target single-depth arrays. Does anyone know of a way to output the contents in a way that would make it easier to tell what contains what?

Ideally something that tabbing, that's the most visually understandable.

Thanks!

---

Edit: Thanks for the fast replies! I didn't know about the  tags. I wish I could select all of them as "best answer"!

Comment: Are these object server-side only? Otherwise, in the browser I’d just log them to console – in most browsers, that gives you the opportunity to “browse” through them, by opening/closing (sub-)arrays and objects … (and even if the are not client-side, maybe that could be a way to go for debugging).

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()`?

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Comment: If you want to see it from the browser instead of the source-code (judging by the `br` tag), wrap the `var_dump()` in `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: All of these work, but they print them out just as messy as the foreach. I'm mostly looking for a method that involves indenting. I should add that to the post.

Comment: Here is the million dollar question: *what is the **result** of json_decode*? (Note how it makes the title and a tag near meaningless and unhelpful.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `var_dump()` indents but reading and browsing the object from the console gives an even better experience.

Comment: @Joshua print_r/var_dump both output the data with newlines and indenting (whitespace) just fine. html just doesn't display the whitespace because in html consecutive whitespace is chopped down to a single whitespace. If you wrap `<pre>` tags around the output, whitespace is shown as expected. Or if you output the var_dump/print_r and view the source of the page, you would see the whitespace as expected.

Comment: Also, I have personally tried to use var_export more as an alternative to var_dump/print_r simply because it outputs the source code representation of the data. Meaning that I can copy/paste it into a file and access it directly without having to fuss with it. Also, we use an auto_prepend file and I just defined a function in there called `adump` that wraps the output with pre-tags so I can simply call `adump($array)` wherever I want to see a variable structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars(print_r($obj,TRUE))."</pre>\n";
```

Comment: only my answer has the `htmlspecialchars()` bonus. if you try to print out some crappy JSON like `array("foo"=>"bar<b><a")` you will be thankful for it...

Answer (score 2):

I agree. This might look good to read

```
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r( $obj );
 echo " </pre>";
```

This also does the indenting.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($obj, true);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: OH MY GOD IT'S BEAUTIFUL

Comment: instead of `echo print_r($obj, true);` i would just do `print_r($obj);`... it's more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have problem with not knowing how many levels of arrays you have. 
You could do a recursive function like this:

```
function echoarray($obj, $i = 0){
    foreach($obj as $key => $val){
        if(isarray($val)) echoarray($val, $i++);
        else echo "$i - $key: $val <br/>";
    }
}
```

Instead of your original `foreach`. Variable `$i` can tell you what level are you on currently.
Take this not as a finished code but as a concept, if it suits your needs.

Basically if current `$val` is array, function `echoarray` is called again and again, until `$val` isn't an array anymore.

Comment: I believe the problem is more that OP wants a way to view the structure so they know what it looks like and how far deep it goes to create loops. Also, just saying, array_walk_recursive.

Comment: Wouldn't `array_walk_recursive` just ignore `$key` when it's `$val` contains an `array`? EDIT: I guess my solution would too :)

Comment: Guess so. However, for just display purposes, any of the print_r/var_dump/var_export offer nicer displays of the data.

Comment: Jonathan has it exactly right. I'm not having trouble creating the proper code to handle it, rather I need to get a good look at what I'm working with. The answers with the <pre> tags were dead on. Outputting to HTML was just a mess without them.